# Detect that a Browser is on the Intranet

Tags: cross-domain, intranet

I've got a requirement to detect if a webpage is being served on the internet or intranet, i.e. assuming a url of https://accessibleanyway.com, is the phone connected to the work wifi or to something else like their home wifi or the phone network?

What different ways are there to do this?

(1) Use WebRTC to get the local ip address. Not widely supported

(2) Try to access a local web page using jsonp/cors/iframe

The problem with 2 is that the webpage is https and the local resource is likely to be http which you can't do in IE afaik. If I make the local resource https then it's via a self cert which means installing CAs on the phones (can you buy certificates for the intranet anymore?)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Detect where, on the server or the client?

Comment: I'm assuming the client but the server is a possibility

Comment: Does the server get the local ip address?

Comment: The server would definitely be seeing a different IP through the cellular network than through the Wifi. In the latter case, it may be the office IP, which may be fixed or easy to recognize

Comment: The problem with this is they could be at home, not connected to the intranet. They have a 192 address at home the same as in work

Comment: So you can use the 192 address to detect when they're on the Intranet, no? And if they don't have one, then they're not.

Comment: Changed question slightly, when I said wifi I meant work wifi

Comment: This isn't enough info - you'd have to explain in detail what your work network looks like, what kinds of IPs the clients get, etc. Just check the client IPs. See what the IP is when connected to the work Wifi, and what it is when not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with (2) was that the same page was trying to use http and https, and even with an iframe you get issues.

What you could do instead is start on a http loading page, use an iframe to access a local resource which you can only access if you are on the intranet, jsonp will work fine for this. Once that's worked or failed, redirect to your start page with some token in the querystring to indicate that you are on the intranet or not

NB jumping from http to https would probably have some security issues if you are on the same website (authentication cookies being initially visible), but I would have thought it would be fine if you are going to a different one

Obviously there'll be some security needed around the token as otherwise the user could just generate their own but that's a different matter which depends on individual setups. It would obviously have to be generated by a server call, otherwise someone could just read the client code.

NB I think the IP address approach is never going to work as you have no way of knowing what a companies intranet setup looks like until you go there, so it's not a generic answer